# Jumio The I'm Ready button isn't working Android (Playstore)

Tags: android

Log example:

m.sdk.x.ι(:312)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t.ǃ(:5414)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t$1.run(:367)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facetec.zoom.sdk.r
2020-10-23 13:41:16.522 31444-604/? W/System.err: ... 6 more
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facetec/zoom/sdk/r;
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.x.ι(:312)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t.ǃ(:5414)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t$1.run(:367)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facetec.zoom.sdk.r
2020-10-23 13:41:16.557 31444-604/? W/System.err: ... 6 more
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facetec/zoom/sdk/r;
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.x.ι(:312)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t.ǃ(:5414)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t$1.run(:367)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facetec.zoom.sdk.r
2020-10-23 13:41:16.589 31444-604/? W/System.err: ... 6 more
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facetec/zoom/sdk/r;
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.x.ι(:312)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t.ǃ(:5414)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at com.facetec.zoom.sdk.t$1.run(:367)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-23 13:41:16.623 31444-604/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facetec.zoom.sdk.r

[image]